# Nested form not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I'm using the cocoon gem to create a nested form. I have an event model that has many tickets and organizers.

EVENT MODEL:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tickets, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tickets, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organizers, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

end
```

ORGANIZER MODEL:

```
class Organizer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :event, presence: true
end
```

TICKET MODEL:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :bookings
end
```

EVENT CONTROLLER:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create 
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    if @event.save
      redirect_to event_path(@event)
    else
      render 'new'
    end 
  end

  def edit
    @event = Event.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @event = Event.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @event.update_attributes event_params
    if @event.save
      redirect_to event_path(@event), flash: { success: "Event updated succesfully." }
    else
      render 'edit'
    end 
  end

  private
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title,:description, tickets_attributes: [:id, :event_id, :title, :limit, :_destroy], organizers_attributes: [:id, :event_id, :user_id, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

NEW VIEW

```
<%= simple_form_for @event, url: events_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :description %> 
  <div id="tickets">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :tickets do |ticket| %>
      <%= render 'ticket_fields', f: ticket %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add ticket', f, :tickets %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="organizers">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :organizers do |organizer| %>
      <%= render 'organizer_fields', f: organizer %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add organizer', f, :organizers %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

ORGANIZERS FIELD PARTIAL:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.input :user, collection: User.all, label_method: lambda { |user| user.email } %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove organizer", f %>
</div>
```

TICKETS FIELD PARTIAL:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :limit, disabled: f.object.no_limit %>
  <%= f.input :no_limit %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove ticket", f %>
</div>
```

SERVER LOGS:

```
Parameters: 
  {
    "utf8"=>"✓", 
    "authenticity_token"=>"rct6..", 
    "event"=>{
      "title"=>"zdtfbvc", 
      "description"=>"fdxcv", 
      "tickets_attributes"=>{
        "1441016179377"=>{
          "title"=>"tdhfgb", 
          "limit"=>"2", 
          "_destroy"=>"false"
        }
      }, 
      "organizers_attributes"=>{
        "1441017842699"=>{
          "user"=>"3", 
          "_destroy"=>"false"
        }, 
        "1441017845556"=>{
          "user"=>"2", 
          "_destroy"=>"false"
        }
      }
    }, 
    "commit"=>"Create Event"
  }
```

The problem is that te tickets are been created and saved to database but the organizers no.

Comment: Can you post the form code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the Organizer Model validates the presence of the event, while the event is not yet created.

If you want to validate in this case you should add `inverse_of` like this:

```
class Organizer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event, inverse_of: :organizers

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :event, presence: true
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizers, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :event
  has_many :tickets, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tickets, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organizers, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods-label-Validating+the+presence+of+a+parent+model

Comment: I have tested your option, but the problem persist. Thanks for your time.